# SVN not committing, showing files as not under control

Tags: linux, svn, centos, commit

Here we can see that SVN is not adding files that need to be added, and not committing:

```
$ ls -la forum
drwxr-xr-x  6 dotan.cohen coders   4096 Apr  9 02:09 before
$ svn status
?       tags
?       forum/before
$ svn add forum/before --force
$ svn status
?       tags
?       forum/before
$ svn commit -m "Some Comment"
$
```

The first command (`ls -la`) shows us that `forum/before/` is in fact a directory. The next command `svn status` shows us that the directory is not under version control. The next line (`svn add`) shows an attempt to add the directory to version control, and the line after it shows that the directory *still* is not under version control. The last line shows that an `svn commit` does nothing, i.e. no commit.

I can confirm that the directory in question is not added to the repository. Why might that be, and how can I fix it? This is on CentOS 5. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the directory in question was copied from another directory under version control. Removing all the `.svn` subdirectories resolved the issue. I used the following command to remove them (from within `forum/before/`):

```
rm -rf `find . -name .svn`
```

Comment: Your `rm` command would be better written as `find . -name ".svn" | xargs rm -rf`. If you had a very deeply nested directory with more than a few thousand files checked in, you would probably fill the environment buffer where the shell keeps its arguments. Using xargs gets around that.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever find yourself in this situation again, I would suggest using `svn switch` rather than deleting the .svn directories. This will re-point all of the URLs. The general syntax is `switch URL[@PEGREV] [PATH]`.